# force SMB to use IPV6 (Windows 10)

Tags: networking, ipv6, smb, ipv4

I am transferring files in 2 ways (bidirectional) frome one computer to another one (with SMB)

[image]

The problem as you see is that one transfer is in IPV6 and the other is in IPV4. the IPv4 connection is using 3,5 MB/s of "overhead" to send at 62 MB/s, IPV6 is using no overhead (2,5 KB/s to receive 60 MB/s) dont know if it is the fact of IPV4 only . IPv6 transfer is more stable too, no ups and downs).

I have verified in netstat -a, there is a socket listening 445 port in IPV6 and an other one in IPV4 on the both computers, so why IPv4 is used in preference on one computer ?

thank you

Comment: You could in theory try disabling IPv4 in the adapter settings.

Comment: We need more info about the two computers.